# Clicking button does not toggle component (when the button and component are in two separate files)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My Layout file:

```
import Menu from "./Menu";
import ButtonMenu from "./ButtonMenu";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="grid h-screen grid-cols-[repeat(4,min-content)] overflow-x-scroll">
        <Menu />
        <Pane1 />
        <Pane2 />
        <Pane3 />
        <div className="w-[100vw]">
          <ButtonMenu />
          <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

My Menu file:

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Menu() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div
      className={` overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll ${ open ? "w-[5vw]" : "w-[20vw]" }`}
    >
      <nav><ul><li></li></ul></nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My ButtonMenu file:

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function OpenMenu() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
       ...
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem I have is simple. **When you click on the `button` (onClick event) that is in the `ButtonMenu` file, then the `Menu` does not open/close, and nothing happens, WHY?.** The `Menu` component is a separate file. The `Menu` file and the `ButtonMenu` file are two components inside my `Layout` file. Why does the `ButtonMenu` does not open/close the `Menu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change something inside the `Menu` component according to a [`state`](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory) variable, it should be defined inside it or passed to it as part of its [`props`](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component). The `open` you created in `ButtonMenu` cannot have any effect on the `Menu`.

If you want to manipulate the menu from different components, you could use a [context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). For that, first, create the below file:

```
// app/MenuContextProvider.tsx

"use client";

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const MenuContext = createContext<{ open: boolean; setOpen: Function }>({
  open: false,
  setOpen: () => {},
});

export default function MenuContextProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  return <MenuContext.Provider value={{ open, setOpen }}>{children}</MenuContext.Provider>;
}

export function useMenuContext() {
  return useContext(MenuContext);
}
```

Change your `Layout.tsx` to:

```
import Menu from "./Menu";
import ButtonMenu from "./ButtonMenu";
import MenuContextProvider from "./MenuContextProvider"
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="grid h-screen grid-cols-[repeat(4,min-content)] overflow-x-scroll">
      <MenuContextProvider>
        <Menu />
        <Pane1 />
        <Pane2 />
        <Pane3 />
        <div className="w-[100vw]">
          <ButtonMenu />
          <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
       </MenuContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The `Menu.tsx` component to:

```
"use client";
import { useMenuContext } from "./MenuContextProvider"
export default function Menu() {
  const {open, setOpen} = useMenuContext();
  return (
    <div
      className={` overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll ${ open ? "w-[5vw]" : "w-[20vw]" }`}
    >
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
       ...
      </button>
      <nav><ul><li></li></ul></nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally your `ButtonMenu.tsx` to:

```
"use client";
import { useMenuContext } from "./MenuContextProvider"
export default function OpenMenu() {
  const {open, setOpen} = useMenuContext();
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
       ...
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Youssof Oumar - impressive! Thank you very much. I have some reading up to do. Does one "context" file work for multiple buttons, each with its own "pane" (pane1, pane2, pane3) that I want to open/close with each its own button?

Comment: If they are all on the same page and should be independent, use another context. You can have as many as you want.

Comment: stuck on this error in the ContextProvider file: "Property {children} is missing in type "{}" but required in type {children: ReactNode};" ...

Comment: Marked the prop children as optional and error disappeared, but the onClick event does not work. Is there another way than to use "context" to make it work? I am using NextJS 13.

Comment: I assume you are getting this error when trying to add multiple contexts? Because there is no way I can see with the solution I had given. If so, please create a new question and paste here its link (as it's a new topic), and I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: My mistake, it works perfectly now. Thank you for offering to help more and ofcourse this solution. I am learning and one day I hope to reach your level of skill. Best wishes!